# ggplot: color geom_bar() borders by group

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to colour the borders of the bars by group (POP in the data) instead of individual points (ID) but can't figure out a way to do it.

My data looks like this:

```
             IND    POP  ancestry   value
    1:  Kharia15 Kharia ancestry1 0.00001
    2:  Kharia14 Kharia ancestry1 0.00001
    3:   Kharia4 Kharia ancestry1 0.00001
    4:   Kharia3 Kharia ancestry1 0.00001
    5:   Kharia1 Kharia ancestry1 0.00001
   ---                                   
18756: HGDP00548 Papuan ancestry8 0.99993
18757: HGDP00554 Papuan ancestry8 0.99993
18758: HGDP00549 Papuan ancestry8 0.99993
18759: HGDP00546 Papuan ancestry8 0.99993
18760: HGDP00540 Papuan ancestry8 0.99993
```

Here's the code

```
ggplot(long_form_combined, aes(x=IND, y=value, fill=ancestry)) +
  geom_bar(position=position_stack(), stat="identity", width=1) +
  ylim(c(-1.2, 1.2)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("ancestry1"="RoyalBlue",
                             "ancestry2"="ForestGreen",
                             "ancestry3"="gold",
                             "ancestry4"="indianred1",
                             "ancestry5"="olivedrab1",
                             "ancestry6"="springgreen",
                             "ancestry7"="sienna",
                             "ancestry8"="skyblue")) +
  coord_polar(start = -1) + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_blank(),
        axis.title.x = element_blank(),
        axis.text.y = element_blank(),
        axis.title.y = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.y = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_blank(),
        legend.title=element_blank())
```

Here's an image of
[what I have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FvH07.png)

and here's an image of
[what I would like to have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TkTT2.jpg)

The ordering of the bars and the centre pie chart don't matter.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In your `aes()` function, you currently specify `x`, `y`, and `fill`. In addition, specify also `color` and give it the same value as `fill`. In other words,

```
ggplot(long_form_combined, aes(x=IND, 
                               y=value, 
                               fill=ancestry,
                               color=ancestry))
```

Comment: The suggestion is colouring the border of every IND, I'd like to "group" IND by POP and colour the border of each POP.